# Is ActionScript a more secure alternative to Flash Player?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

With all the security issues with Flash lately I am looking at alternatives for if/when Flash is retired at my work. We use strictly IE 11 and IE11 seems to be very finicky about css3 animations. I see the new Flash has the ability to publish the file as embeddable actionscript files instead of a swf file. Is this a viable alternative to Flash or is this vulnerable to the same security issues Flash has? My assumption is the vulnerabilities exist in the Flash players but I want to be certain.

Comment: What's amazing is that a company seek to drop a technology while having so little knowledge about it.

Comment: I am trying to be prepared in the event it does get phased out. I am very much a novice at these things thus the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Apples and Oranges, really.

The Flash Player is a runtime environment of the Flash platform  (AIR being another). It "plays" .swf files.

ActionScript is the scripting language that an apropriate compiler (mxmlc, for example) compiles into .swf files.

> I see the new Flash has the ability to publish the file as embeddable ActionScript files instead of a swf file.

You can embed any file, but guess where you embed it into? Into the swf file.

Again, ActionScript is the programing/scripting language and an swf file is the compiled result.

---

Flash CC can also export to JavaScript/HTML/CSS. That means that instead of creating a .swf file, a bunch of JavaScript/HTML/CSS files are created.

As you can see in the link you provided, the feature sets are not equivalent.

> **Note:** The 3D Rotation tool in the toolbar of the Flash Professional CC workspace is disabled when creating HTML5 Canvas documents because it is specific to SWF projects and not supported in the HTML5 specification (see Figure 3).

[There's a whole bunch of other things not supported](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/unsupported-features-html5-canvas1.html)

### Recommendation

If one comes to the conclusion that the Flash platform is not an appropriate publishing platform any more, why bother sticking to the Adobe Flash program?

It appears to be disadvantageous to cling to the program, just for the sake of keep on using it.

Why not use the [CreateJS](http://www.createjs.com/) library on its own? Or any of the other dozens of great JS libraries? There's a lot to explore in the post-Flash era and it is very exiting. It's not a good idea to stay behind, still coding in dead languages, hoping that there's a translator to communicate with the Present. Try to order a pizza in Latin and you know what I mean.

If the goal is to target multiple different platforms, there are alternative tools to do this like [defrac](https://www.defrac.com/) or [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) that allow you to compile from one languages to many platforms.

The answer to the question if compiling ActionScript to JavaScript/HTML/CSS is a reasonable workflow for the future is no. It might be a good tool to port existing projects, but not to neglect the current developments in the JavaScript/HTML/CSS realm.

Comment: The feature I am referring to is: http://www.adobe.com/inspire/2014/02/flash-html5-canvas.html I guess reading it further it uses javascript instead of actionscript? I thought actionscript was involved somehow but it does explicitly say it doesn't use a plugin. This would be convenient especially for converting existing flash files. I just want to be sure it solves the security issue before investing in an expensive license.

Comment: @CodeJack please add that link to your question. I edited my answer to take it into account.

Comment: medio caseum pizza partus

Answer (score 2):

I seem to get almost weekly Java updates. All these technologies can have security issues, it's just that Adobe react quickly, and release a fix as soon as possible. That does come with a certain amount of publicity.

About using CreateJS on its own, you could do that, and come up with your own libraries to create hierarchy, synchronizing sound to visual events, asset management, etc. You could also do everything purely in code, if your imagination is good enough to do that. Or, you could just use Flash Pro, and get all of those things for free.